# How do I make a python script (including its dependencies) run on startup of an Ubuntu machine?

Tags: ubuntu, script, boot, python

Well, I do know that for a single script the question is to just put the corresponding file in directory `/etc/rc.local`, right? But, what if this script depends on other files (i.e. a few scripts and a couple of text files)? What should I do in order to avoid making this certain folder a mess?

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` is not a directory but a simple file.

Comment: Alright. But either way the question stills. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

If by **depends**, you mean it **uses and/or calls** them, that **should not matter**. You can just add a line to the end of the rc.local file as a command to call the main script and it **should just work**.

There is an **alternative to rc.local**, atleast on desktop versions. You can use the **`Startup Applications`** app to add your script to it. The difference between the two methods, other than  CLI vs GUI version of adding is that **rc.local scripts** are run as **ROOT** and the **startup applications as your user**.

---

#### Edit

From the comments, your problem becomes **clearer**. It seems that the script is using **relative paths** to access the dependency, which I'm guessing isn't code. The working directory of the above two methods are either `/root/` or `/home/<user name/`, thus the **dependencies dont load**.

Easiest fix is to **`cd` to the folder** before invoking the python script. Either of these should work:
- Use `cd /home/..../.../ && python perdc_task.py` as the command in either of those two methods.
- If that doesnt work, make a script(`.sh` should do) which calls the above command and call this script in the above 2 methods.

The more elegant way of doing it is
- Do the `cd` from **inside the python script** by programatically determining its path
- Or Use the above path to access the dependencies by **absolute path**

---

#### Edit2

Ubuntu might have moved away from rc.local in favor of [upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart). Try to see if using upstart as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783341/run-script-with-rc-local-script-works-but-not-at-boot) works for you.

Comment: I would prefer the GUI version. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I used this command: python /home/.../.../.../perdc_task.py Any ideas?

Comment: either of these methods should work, and yet they dont.. sounds like there might be something you are missing.. what do you mean it doesnt work? Try to write out a log to see if it is starting.. is it possible it is running but terminating or something?

Comment: try `python /home/.../.../.../perdc_task.py > /home/<your username>/Documents/perdc_task.log` and check out if anything is written into the log file

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, a strange thing is happening. The above script doesn’t run unless I do CD so that the current directory is where the script is located. If I do that, everything works fine and noting is written on the log file. If I don't do that, an error message is shown in terminal, however nothing is written on the log file. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried it but still have problems. Now the scripts are executed directly through the console (I mean, without the need of doing cd beforehand), however I face problems when I use the startup application feature of Ubuntu. Any help on that?

Comment: do you mean a cd isnt helping any more? or is there some other problem with the startup applications?

Comment: Exactly. It seems there's a problem with the startup applications...

Comment: elabourate pls?

Comment: Lets start again:

I write the following lines:

`#!/bin/bash`
`python /home/<USER>/<PATH>/perdc_task.py`
`exit 0`

At the end of file:

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

But it stills not working. What should I do?

Comment: can you try the earlier suggestion of redirecting the output to a log file and seeing if there is any output? and to confirm, you say `cd /; python /home/<USER>/<PATH>/perdc_task.py` is working with no problem?

Comment: I have good news! The output file was created successfully, however, it is empty, which means that the script works prefect! However, I noticed that the bash script didn't started automatically (i.e. with the startup of the machine) (I know that because the output file was not there, but it was created only when I called the bash script from the command line as `sh /etc/rc.local`). Therefore, I believe that the problem will be solved only when I make this file run at start up. But, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `cron` enabled (which you should) there is a special `@reboot` command which runs on startup. I am unsure of this works on cold boots though, but from what I can see it does.

If it works, you just write a script, plonk it in some clean and organised directory, then call it through `cron`.

See: [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/) and [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)